# Is there any modern way of calculating custom view 's height?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, tableview

I use a custom view as a tableView 's tableHeaderView . It contains some stackView and some multi-line labels

[image]

and because I use this custom View as a tableHeaderView ,so I have to provide a height for it the same as I have done thousand time before .

[image]

As the code above, I have to manually calculate label height use sizeThatFit and so on.

But sometimes I ask my web developing colleagues about how they develop such pages, is it the same in web developing that contains so many manually calculating, they say it will be more simple in web developing of such page, there will be no such manual calculation included.

So I think maybe there are some more modern way to getting height of the custom view , to avoid so many tedious work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to get the dynamic height for your custom view.

Just add this in `viewDidLoad:`

```
self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = XX; // estimated height
```

No need to implement `heightForHeaderInSection`

Comment: I think UITableViewAutomaticDimension will works on UITableViewCells only? does it will also works with tableHeaderView?

Comment: Yes, its possible.

Comment: thanks ,but in my situation , the custom view is used as a tableHeaderView not a section headerView , in my test before , the UITableViewAutomaticDimension is not working on tableHeaderView

Comment: I think you may need to revisit the constraints in your customview if the above solution is not working.

Comment: what does  'revisit' mean? rebuild ?